# I cannot close the update window when install through synptic (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: synaptics

I have install flashplugin package through synaptic but there was a update information box which I cannot close it (**I close it temporarily and then it appears on other day when I start the computer**).
[image]

As I check the syslog file in /var. Here the result when I click the `run this action now` button :

```
Jul 28 15:21:25 TrinhHuy dbus-daemon[1475]: [session uid=1000 pid=1475] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.95' (uid=1000 pid=4035 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real -- pkexec /usr/lib/up" label="unconfined")
Jul 28 15:21:25 TrinhHuy systemd[1463]: Created slice apps.slice.
Jul 28 15:21:25 TrinhHuy systemd[1463]: Created slice apps-org.gnome.Terminal.slice.
Jul 28 15:21:25 TrinhHuy systemd[1463]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Jul 28 15:21:26 TrinhHuy dbus-daemon[1475]: [session uid=1000 pid=1475] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Jul 28 15:21:26 TrinhHuy systemd[1463]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Jul 28 15:21:26 TrinhHuy systemd[1463]: Started VTE child process 4049 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 4038.
Jul 28 15:21:26 TrinhHuy systemd[1463]: vte-spawn-b702640c-f872-4180-aa93-6cbeca1280e9.scope: Succeeded.
Jul 28 15:21:26 TrinhHuy systemd[1463]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Succeeded.
```

Thanks for reading. How can I fix this issue ?